# How to calculate the number of longs (64-bits) necessary to store N bits?

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Well, I can do that through logic, but I bet there is a mathematical operation or expression to do that. Does one exist? If yes, what is it?

Here is the algorithm:

```
private int calcNumberOfLongs(int size) {
    if (size % 64 == 0) {
        return size / 64;
    } else {
        return size / 64 + 1;
    }
}
```

---

Let me be clear what I want:

For 150 bits I need three 64-bit longs. Two of course only gives me 128 bits. So that's the first computation.

The second computation, this one even more important because it will be executed all the time, is to go from bit position to long. For example:

```
bit 5 -> first long
bit 64 -> first long
bit 65 -> second long
bit 140 -> third long
```

What is the mathematical expression and / or bitwise operation to get this information?

---

Ok, from the answer below it looks like to go from bit position to long, we just use:

long position = bit position / 64

The continuation is here: [How to turn a division into a bitwise shift when power of two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784685/how-to-turn-a-division-into-a-bitwise-shift-when-power-of-two)

Comment: What's wrong with always   return size / 64 + 1;

Comment: @aviad Because that'd return 2 when size = 64, when the correct answer is 1.

Comment: @Kshitij Mehta - smart a**s :)  aviad was basically correct.  How about `((return size - 1) / 64) + 1`.  Or better, as PeterJ said: `(size + GRANULE_SIZE - 1) / GRANULE_SIZE`, here `(size + 63) / 64`.

Comment: @Kshitij Mehta, who cares?

Comment: @chrisapotek: also consider using Java [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there is a built-in function to do it although you could simplify your code to:

```
return (size + 63) / 64;
```

Comment: simplest answer, Long.SIZE can be used to make it look move universal

Comment: How did you know that? I mean, what is the mathematical rationale behind that expression?

Comment: Yeah, this is an expression that's needed frequently in code that allocates buffers, etc.  Good to become familiar with it.  Generic is `(size + GRANULE_SIZE - 1) / GRANULE_SIZE`

Comment: (It makes use of the properties of integer arithmetic.)

Comment: How do you go from bit position to index? Same expression?